# Why Ansible get_url gives error about checksums?

Tags: ansible, checksum, geturl

I have a task in my ansible playbook, that downloads a java archive from a github url.
The task is here:

```
- name: Download Jar Plugin
  get_url:
    url: https://GitHub-URL/plugins-1.0.5.jar
    dest: /app/plugins/
```

There's no mention of checksum, yet it gives this error:

```
fatal: [host]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "attempted to take checksum of directory: /app/plugins/plugins-1.0.5.jar"}
```

anyone has any idea about this? Is there any workaround to make it download this java archive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all GitHub is not the right location to keep binaries. Github does not allow us to store a single file greater than 100 MB in most cases. You you should have binaries kept in either a physical server or any cloud storage and pull it from there.

Now, if you are really inclined to follow this bad practise I suggest you to create an equivalent unix `curl` first to do that. If you have an existing `curl` command to do that share that with us or simply use ansible `shell` module as a starting point. You can also try increasing timeouts as default is 10 secs only. Here's a snippet where timeout is set to 200 seconds.

```
- name: Download Jar Plugin
  get_url:
    url: https://GitHub-URL/plugins-1.0.5.jar
    dest: /app/plugins/
    timeout: 200
```

Comment: `curl -o /app/plugins/plugins-1.0.5.jar --create-dir https://github.com/app/plugins/plugins-1.0.5.jar` **OK** here's a sample this works with correct URL..

Comment: @SS-eth0 try increasing the timeout as default is only 10 secs. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/get_url_module.html#parameter-timeout

Comment: surprisingly setting high timeout in playbook worked, but I'm confused and can't relate to its reason. any pointer?

Comment: @SS-eth0 timeout is the period that Ansible waits to get a response from a requests. Your request's response is heasully takes more than 10 secs even from curl request, hence, increasing timeout will work.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding checksum argument as below:

```
- name: Download Jar Plugin
  get_url:
   url: https://GitHub-URL/plugins-1.0.5.jar
   dest: /app/plugins/
   timeout: 200
   checksum: <yourchecksum>
```

Hope this helps as per your error.

Comment: ty @Santosh for contribution, but in my case I had no checksum, just needed to download the file.